# Adding Swipe function to customized lock screen

Tags: android, android-screen

I've been working on making customized lock screen.

I think I succeeded on making view come up when the screen is turned on.

However, I am wondering how I can make my app realize user's swipe activity in order to make screen go to the home screen just like the normal android lock screen does.

Any suggestion will be very helpful thx!

Comment: Just detect Horizontal or Vertical Swipe using Gesture Detector and exit from app by finishing all activities..

Comment: Hmm.. is it possible to link any samples or reference code for it? since I ain't a professional android app coder..

Comment: yes I'l post it as my answer

Comment: @jae park cau tell me how you suceed on making view come up when the screen is turn on. plz help me,, i am stuck there.. i have no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples to detect right,left,up and down swipes.You can detect any of the swipes and finish all activities to exit from your app.

[Example 1](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118)

[Example 2](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/)

[Example 3](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/detect-swap-event-in-android.html)

You can ask if you have any further queries.Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks I'll check on it